# If statement with list is producing inaccurate output

Tags: python

Code is:

```
import random

Cards = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]

user = int(input("Number\n"))
print(Cards[user])

computer = int(input("Number\n"))
print(Cards[computer])

if Cards[user] > Cards[computer]:
    print(f"You win {user} {computer}")
else:
    print(f"You Lose {computer} {user}")
```

Output is:

> Number
> 11
> K
> Number
> 12
> A
> You win 11 12

Its meant to say "You Lose" Since K as in king of cards is lower than an A which stands for Ace. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please use codeblocks

Comment: How would Python know (without you telling it somehow) that "K" is a king and "A" is an ace and that ace > king?  What would you expect it to say if you asked it to compare, say, "X" and "Y"?

Comment: Maybe you want to compare `user` and `computer` directly (since those are numeric indices that correspond to the positions of the cards in your value-ascending list) rather than `Cards[user]` and `Cards[computer]`...?

Comment: Im new to coding but doesn't the if statement compare between the [user] and [computer] or am I doing it wrong? I get what you mean but based on the coding I tried to execute I thought it would compare the numbers that I had inputted for user and computer. What would be the correct way to solve this. I really want to understand. Thanks for responding

Comment: You said `if Cards[user] > Cards[computer]:` which means you're comparing `Cards[user]` (which is `"K"`) to `Cards[computer]` (which is `"A"`).  If you want to compare `user` (which is `11`) and `computer` (which is `12`) do `if user > computer:`.

Comment: I get your saying Sam. What I was trying to accomplish is showing what card is more greater. For example I would want the output to display that "I win" because A is greater than K. Hopefully i'm making sense here but I am very appreciative of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should compare the index which orders the cards by value

```py
import random

Cards = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]

user = int(input("Number\n"))
print(Cards[user])

computer = int(input("Number\n"))
print(Cards[computer])

if user > computer:  # Changed here
    print(f"You win {user} {computer}")
else:
    print(f"You Lose {computer} {user}")
```

Comment: `int(input("Number\n"))` will raise an error if it's "J", "Q", "K" or "A"

Comment: `int(input("Number\n"))` refers to the index of the `Cards` list. No reason to pass the char you've mentioned.

Comment: Ah okay well then I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @maggle, the way to do it is to just compare the integers user and computer.

Comparing the indexes (as stated by @puncher) does not work, as `Cards.index("11")` will return `ValueError` (as the integer 11 is not in the list cards).

Comment: the list has a length of 13 hence 11 can be used to index a _value_ of the list... just test it. Guess you mixed with index/value

Comment: Sorry, but I am quite confused. If the user inputs "11", as they did in the example, how will cards.index("11") return a value (as @puncher suggests)? And why does maggle's not work? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I just read this post a moment ago. Yes, you right...why don't right it properly and maybe add a solution on how to fix it? PS `Cards.index("11")` raises `ValueError`

Comment: Sorry, I was just agreeing with maggle. I am relatively new to Stack Overflow so I apologise if it is an obvious question but should I just copy maggle's code and add it as my solution? Or what would be best? Thanks (and sorry that I forgot about the ValueError).

Comment: no worries. the answer you mentioned doesn't work because `int(input(...))` with `J`, `Q`,... cannot be cast to integer. Try to find your way... the question has no "solution" upto now:)

Comment: But the value the user inputs is a number (as shown in the example, where they inputted 11. Perhaps there should be some validation of the user input, but the user is not supposed to input J, Q... to my understanding. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This behavior occurs because you are comparing strings, rather than ints.

For the **card game** the following ordering is correct

```
>>> "J"<"Q"<"K"<"A" # <- PSEUDO CODE!
True
```

but **strings** are subjects by default to the alphabetical ordering

```
>>> "J"<"Q"<"K"<"A"
False
>>> "A"<"J"<"K"<"Q"
True
```

So, the condition `Cards[user] > Cards[computer]` is between strings that's why the output is different from the expected one.

As the "cards" are arranged in ascending order, you only need to check if `user` is greater than `computer`. This will compare ints and work the way you expect.

As an aside, you should be verifying that the index you get from the user is a valid one for the length of the list. There are many ways to do this.